# Build Kibana : repeating "restarting server due to changes in "src\core_plugins\kibana\index.js""

Tags: node.js, kibana, kibana-4

I am trying to build kibana-4.5.0 in my Windows-7 machine (64 bit)
following the doc : https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

but , when running the command `npm start` , 
its repeatedly restarting the endlessly [running command from a git-bash]

[image]

Comment: Same to me too. Have you found answer?

Comment: @AungSatt didnt find answer, I finally installed in a debian virtual-machine